# don't show modal dialog in certain condition

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I used the codes here http://jsfiddle.net/0gct8qd8/ to create a modal dialog when the submit button is pressed. But what should I do if I want to, let's say, due to certain condition is not met (eg the last name's length is less than 3), I don't want the modal dialog to be displayed.

Here's what I done so far but to no avail

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
        if (verifyAllInput() == true){
             $('#confirmNRIC').text($('#ID').val());
             $('#confirmMobile').text($('#MobileNo').val());
             $('#confirmEmail').text($('#Email').val());            
        }else{          
             //this part here should make the modal not being displayed
             alert("ttaa");

            $( "#confirm-submit" ).hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show model programmatically. Remove from `#submitBtn` attribute `data-toggle` and add to your script `$('#confirm-submit').modal('show');`.